# RegEx code to find duplicate (parts of) sentences anywhere in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: duplicates, wildcard, regex-lookarounds, find-replace, libreoffice-writer

I have created a RegEx code to find the following:
- strings, or parts of strings (at least 5 consecutive words), that appear at least twice in the whole scope of text
- the whole scope of text is in tables.
/\b([\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]+)(?=.*\b\1{1,})/gm
[image]
I only used this part of the RegEx, since LibreOffice does not want to recognize the whole RegEx above:
\b([\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}[\w]+)(?=.*\b\1{1,})

**The problem:**
- the RegEx ONLY finds parts of a text that appears IN THE SAME segment, but not intersegmentally. The whole text is in scope.
The red underlined text (the one I underlined) in the right segment should also be found, but it was not. IOW: **I want to mark duplicates even if they appear somewhere else in the document/another cell.**
[image]

I have tried ChatGPT in OpenAI, but to no avail.
**Please, help. I also use MS Word, so wildcards are also ok.**

Comment: Writer doesn't match across text sections, so you could save as text and then perform the regex in the text file.

Comment: Note: It's a good idea to mention what you've tried, for example, if you've searched online forums for related answers. However, don't include ChatGPT, because it often generates nothing but noise, especially if you're attempting something you're not familiar with. Sure, go ahead and try it, but don't include it in the discussion, and especially, don't post any code generated by it.

Comment: I've tried saving the document as .txt, but my RegEx still does not find duplicates when they are far apart in the text. 
\b([\w]{1,}[\s\,]{1,}[\w]{1,}[\s\,]{1,}[\w]+)(?=.*\b\1{1,})
It seems as if the lookahead only matches another sentence if in the same paragraph. 
Is there a way to match any characters including line breaks, or shall I just remove all line breaks from the text (cumbersome)?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/search_regexp.html:

> A search using a regular expression will work only within one paragraph.

But with plain text, there's no need to limit yourself to LibreOffice. For example, there are text editors such as Vim, command line tools such as grep, or programming languages such as Perl (or modern languages such as Python that use the same concept with a bit more code required).

For a solution that doesn't require anything in particular on your system, use the following web site (the example is included in the link): https://regex101.com/r/pF3EN3/1

In that example, I used the following regex:

```
/\b((?:[\w]{1,}[\s]{1,}){4}[\w]+)(?=.*\b\1{1,})/s
```

The important part is the `/s` flag at the end, meaning that the input will be treated as a **single** line so that `.` matches line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanataion and a RegEx.
I've tried it from different angles, but whenever the text is longer (even after removal of line breaks), it causes so-called "catastrophic backtracking". Do you have any idea on how to avoid it in this case?
It's necessary for me to use long texts to find the duplicates.
(I don´t know how to paste the screenshot in here, but I used the long text from this link as an example, and when pasted twice, it should automatically mark the very most of the text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)

Comment: Good question, but it's no longer the same as the original, so you should post it as a different one that is only about regex text matching and not about LibreOffice or MS Word, so that you'll get answers from people who know about that specifically. Include a link to this question for context, and be sure to research the new issue — especially, search for related questions that have been posted on SO.